# Album art is lost when converting 24 bit alac to 16 bit using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert apple lossless files to 16 bits for playback on an old ipod.
My problem is that I loose the album art.

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -acodec alac -sample_fmt s16p output.m4a
```

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I used a strange version of ffmpeg that converted the cover to h264. Using the official binary release and adding `-codec copy` fixed the issue.

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -codec copy -acodec alac -sample_fmt s16p output.m4a
```

Comment: And as in the time of writing this comment includes ffmpeg installed from apt on ubuntu 18.04, `-codec copy` wont work, it will only want to convert it to h264. Use the "Static Build" on the ffmpeg website. Tested both Linux and windows versions.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 uses FFmpeg 3.4 release branch which is old.